# PHP DOM appendeing children elements to root

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to append children elements to a pre-loaded root element like below

```
    $document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $document->loadXML('<books></books>');


    $content = '<books>
                   <book>
                       <athors>
                           <athor>
                               <name>John Doe</name>
                           </athor>
                       </athors>
                   </book>
               </books>';
     
    $books = new DOMDocument()

    $books->loadXML($content);

    foreach ($books as $book){
        $document->appendChild($document->importNode( $book, true ));
    }
```

For some reason, the result xml document will be like below, with the closing tag of the root element at the beginning of the document:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <books/>
         <book>
                       <athors>
                           <athor>
                               <name>John Doe</name>
                           </athor>
                       </athors>
          </book>
```

I want it to be like below:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <books>
         <book>
                       <athors>
                           <athor>
                               <name>John Doe</name>
                           </athor>
                       </athors>
          </book>
   <books/>
```

Comment: What are you trying to append exactly? The before and after look the same.

Comment: @JackFleeting The second line is `<books/>` instead of `<books>`

Comment: @Barmar As far as I can see, the structure of both `$content` and the expected output is `books/book/authors/author/name`; but then again, it's been a long day already...

Comment: But the output he's getting is NOT that structure. He's trying to merge `$content` into `$document`.

Comment: @Barmar Got it; `$document` is empty at first. As I said, long day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over the children of the root element in `$books`, not the `book` elements. And then you're appending to the root of `$document`, not the `books` element.

You need to drill down in each to get to the appropriate nodes.

```
<?php
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$document->loadXML('<books></books>');
$documentBooks = $document->childNodes[0];

$content = '<books>
                   <book>
                       <athors>
                           <athor>
                               <name>John Doe</name>
                           </athor>
                       </athors>
                   </book>
               </books>';
     
$books = new DOMDocument();
$books->loadXML($content);
$bookItems = $books->childNodes[0]->childNodes;

foreach ($bookItems as $book){
    $documentBooks->appendChild($document->importNode( $book, true ));
}
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Comment: thank you but I am trying to append it in the intial `$document` object, not to create a new one.

Comment: This doesn't create a new document object, it just appends it to the correct place in the document. You were appending it to the root, but it needs to be appended to the `<books>` element.

Comment: ok. If you can kindly asssit on how I can then save it to XML, because `$documentBooks `is just a DOMelement but I need to save the final DOMdocument using `$document->saveXML()`

Comment: That should work fine. `$documentBooks` is a reference to a child of `$document`.

Comment: `$documentBooks = $document->documentElement;` is a better (more specific) option.